# wmic to disable all network adapters

Tags: networking, wmic

I know how to use wmic to disable specific network card using below commend, but I would like to disable all network card from the index, could you please tell me what should I change in my command?

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=1 call disable
```

or If you have better option I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Did you even try to drop the where clause?